# How to add a Title and legend in Processing(Java) and create diverging colors

Tags: java, image, processing

I currently have a code to map poverty rates to states using processing. I want to add a Title above the map and a legend detailing colors. Currently I only have values in red, I also need help in creating diverging colors from green(low values) to red(High values).[Link to files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AiF_fSDud6PZmZ14elXDhOOQhF1o8fER?usp=sharing) Below is my code:

```
PImage mapImage;
Table locationTable;
int rowCount;
Table dataTable;
float dataMin = MAX_FLOAT;
float dataMax = MIN_FLOAT;
int toggle = 0;
void setup( ) {
size(640, 400);
  surface.setTitle("Poverty Rate by State");
  surface.setResizable(true);
  surface.setLocation(100, 100);

mapImage = loadImage("map.png");
locationTable = new Table("locations.tsv");
rowCount = locationTable.getRowCount( );
// Read the data table.
dataTable = new Table("poverty2017.tsv");
// Find the minimum and maximum values.
for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
float value = dataTable.getFloat(row, 1);
if (value > dataMax) {
dataMax = value;
}
if (value < dataMin) {
dataMin = value;
}
}
}

void draw( ) {
background(255);
image(mapImage, 0, 0);
smooth( );
fill(192, 0, 0);
noStroke( );
for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
String abbrev = dataTable.getRowName(row);
float x = locationTable.getFloat(abbrev, 1);
float y = locationTable.getFloat(abbrev, 2);
drawData(x, y, abbrev);
}
}

void drawData(float x, float y, String abbrev) {
float value = dataTable.getFloat(abbrev, 1);
float radius = 0;
if (value >= 0) {
radius = map(value, 0, dataMax, 1.5, 15);
fill(#FF4422); // Red
} else {
radius = map(value, 0, dataMin, 1.5, 15);
fill(#FF4422); // red
}
ellipseMode(RADIUS);
ellipse(x, y, radius, radius);
if (dist(x, y, mouseX, mouseY) < radius+2) {
fill(0);
textAlign(CENTER);
// Show the data value and the state abbreviation in parentheses.
text(value + " (" + abbrev + ")", x, y-radius-4);
}
}
```

With the following class to pull the data in as circles:

```
class Table {
  String[][] data;
  int rowCount;


  Table() {
    data = new String[10][10];
  }


  Table(String filename) {
    String[] rows = loadStrings(filename);
    data = new String[rows.length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      if (trim(rows[i]).length() == 0) {
        continue; // skip empty rows
      }
      if (rows[i].startsWith("#")) {
        continue;  // skip comment lines
      }

      // split the row on the tabs
      String[] pieces = split(rows[i], TAB);
      // copy to the table array
      data[rowCount] = pieces;
      rowCount++;

      // this could be done in one fell swoop via:
      //data[rowCount++] = split(rows[i], TAB);
    }
    // resize the 'data' array as necessary
    data = (String[][]) subset(data, 0, rowCount);
  }


  int getRowCount() {
    return rowCount;
  }


  // find a row by its name, returns -1 if no row found
  int getRowIndex(String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      if (data[i][0].equals(name)) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    println("No row named '" + name + "' was found");
    return -1;
  }


  String getRowName(int row) {
    return getString(row, 0);
  }


  String getString(int rowIndex, int column) {
    return data[rowIndex][column];
  }


  String getString(String rowName, int column) {
    return getString(getRowIndex(rowName), column);
  }


  int getInt(String rowName, int column) {
    return parseInt(getString(rowName, column));
  }


  int getInt(int rowIndex, int column) {
    return parseInt(getString(rowIndex, column));
  }


  float getFloat(String rowName, int column) {
    return parseFloat(getString(rowName, column));
  }


  float getFloat(int rowIndex, int column) {
    return parseFloat(getString(rowIndex, column));
  }


  void setRowName(int row, String what) {
    data[row][0] = what;
  }


  void setString(int rowIndex, int column, String what) {
    data[rowIndex][column] = what;
  }


  void setString(String rowName, int column, String what) {
    int rowIndex = getRowIndex(rowName);
    data[rowIndex][column] = what;
  }


  void setInt(int rowIndex, int column, int what) {
    data[rowIndex][column] = str(what);
  }


  void setInt(String rowName, int column, int what) {
    int rowIndex = getRowIndex(rowName);
    data[rowIndex][column] = str(what);
  }


  void setFloat(int rowIndex, int column, float what) {
    data[rowIndex][column] = str(what);
  }


  void setFloat(String rowName, int column, float what) {
    int rowIndex = getRowIndex(rowName);
    data[rowIndex][column] = str(what);
  }


  // Write this table as a TSV file
  void write(PrintWriter writer) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        if (j != 0) {
          writer.print(TAB);
        }
        if (data[i][j] != null) {
          writer.print(data[i][j]);
        }
      }
      writer.println();
    }
    writer.flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow that's a lot of work! Good job btw, sure there's room for improvement but you got most of the job done. I notice that you are doing _a lot_ of computing every time you draw a frame... was this deliberated, or is it accident? I'm asking because the data doesn't seem to change between frames. Oh and btw nice post, I got it working without any fuss.

Comment: @laancelot Thanks for the help, I was able to rework the examples from Benfry to get my data working. As for the computing it wasn't intentional this is a new language and I am learning it so this will be helpful.  I will let you know if I have anymore issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a title: just add some text to your draw loop.

```
void draw() {
  AddTitle();
}

void AddTitle() {
  fill(0);
  textSize(20);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  text("Poverty Rate by State", width/2, 30);
}
```

To change the color of your red circles so states are on a scale from green (least poverty) to red (max poverty):

You're working in RGB (Red-Green-Blue). Each color is a mix of these. Those tree are calculated with numbers on a scale from 0 to 255. For an example, black would be (0, 0, 0), red would be (255, 0, 0). The lower the number the least of the specific color is in the mix.

```
color myColorRed = color(255, 0, 0);
```

So to make your fill dynamic, you have to find a way to *increase* the red part when your poverty rate increases, while lowering the green part at the same time. Here's a simple calcul which does exactly that:

```
float colorOffset = 255 * ((povertyRate - dataMin) / (dataMax - dataMin));
color(colorOffset, 255-colorOffset, 0);
```

You can just include this at the right place in your logic and it should do the trick. Beware, though: this calcul is based on the dataMin and dataMax. This means that the lowest number will be green and the highest will be red, not that 0% is green and 100% is red. You'll probably like it this way, but if you wanted something else you'll have to adapt this logic to what you want.

Now... something is bothering me here. At every iteration of the `draw()` loop, you re-calculate a lot of information. That's a lot of processing power wasted. Of course, with a good computer there will be no difference, but it would be good practice to avoid wasting resources like that. A good way to fix this would be to calculate everything you need to know to draw your map in the `setup()` method, and use it in the `draw()` loop.

Now, If you're not interested in what I just said, consider that you have your answer and you can skip the rest. If you'd like to improve a bit on your current algorithm, let's rock!

---

First, I gathered all the information you need in a nice new class:

```
class StateData {
  public String name;
  public PVector location; // I'll just use this to have nice x and y floats, but there's a lot of nice stuff available with this class (which I won't use here)
  public float povertyRate;
  public float radius;
  public color fill;

  StateData(String name, PVector location, float povertyRate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.povertyRate = povertyRate;
    this.radius = map(povertyRate, 0, dataMax, 1.5, 15);

    float colorOffset = 255 * ((povertyRate - dataMin) / (dataMax - dataMin));
    this.fill = color(colorOffset, 255-colorOffset, 0);
  }
}
```

Naturally, I'll need to fill these and store this information somewhere. I created a global variable:

```
ArrayList<StateData> stateData;
```

I'll fill this global variable by using the following function in the `setup()` method, so I'll need to calculate all these things only once:

```
ArrayList<StateData> GetStateData() {
  ArrayList<StateData> data = new ArrayList<StateData>();

  for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
    String abbrev = dataTable.getRowName(row);
    float value = dataTable.getFloat(abbrev, 1);
    float x = locationTable.getFloat(abbrev, 1);
    float y = locationTable.getFloat(abbrev, 2);
    data.add(new StateData(abbrev, new PVector(x, y), value));
  }

  return data;
}
```

You'll notice that I'm mostly just recycling your code, here. That's because your code *gets the job done*. It's good work. It's just very inefficient, and this should help on this front.

By now, your `setup()` method should look like somthing like this:

```
void setup() {
  size(640, 400);
  smooth();
  noStroke();

  mapImage = loadImage("map.png");
  locationTable = new Table("locations.tsv");
  rowCount = locationTable.getRowCount( );
  dataTable = new Table("poverty2017.tsv");
  for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
    float value = dataTable.getFloat(row, 1);
    if (value > dataMax) {
      dataMax = value;
    }
    if (value < dataMin) {
      dataMin = value;
    }
  }

  stateData = GetStateData();
}
```

And your `draw()` loop like this:

```
void draw() {
  background(255);
  image(mapImage, 0, 0);

  DrawStats();
  AddTitle();
}
```

Wait...­ what's `DrawStats()`? That's a method which will loop in the `stateData` ArrayList and draw everything according to the data stored there while we were in the `setup()` method:

```
void DrawStats() {
  // draw circles
  for (StateData s : stateData) {
    fill(s.fill);
    ellipseMode(RADIUS);
    ellipse(s.location.x, s.location.y, s.radius, s.radius);
  }
  // draw text (here so it's over the circles)
  for (StateData s : stateData) {
    if (dist(s.location.x, s.location.y, mouseX, mouseY) < s.radius+2) {
      fill(0);
      textAlign(CENTER);
      textSize(10);
      text(s.povertyRate + " (" + s.name + ")", s.location.x, s.location.y-s.radius-4);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, with these pointers and a little bit of refactoring, you should be able to give a nice quality boost to this program! I'll hang around in case you have further questions.

Have fun!